# Uniform grid estimation for an integral by E.T. Jaynes

Tags: analysis

E.T. Jaynes writes in "Probability Theory: The Logic of Science" (Chapter 17.7, page 531):

> Let a function y = f(x) have its domain of existence in the unit square $0 \leq x, y \leq 1$; we wish to compute the integral
> $$\theta = \int_0^1 \mathrm{d} x f(x).$$
> ...
> Now let's take our sampling points in a nonrandomized way on a uniform grid:
> divide the unit square into $\sqrt{n}$ steps each way, take one sampling point at each grid, and again count how many ($r$) are below [the graph of $f(x)$]. The maximum error we can make in each step is
>
> $$[\text{error in determining }f(x)]\times[\text{width of step}] = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2n}.$$
> Therefore the maximum possible error in the integral is
> $$[\text{number of steps}] \times [\text{maximum error in each step}] = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}.$$

I don't follow this derivation, specifically:

- error in determening $f(x)$

I checked [Unofficial Errata and Commentary for E. T. Jaynes's Probability Theory: The Logic of Science](http://ksvanhorn.com/bayes/jaynes/) and no mistakes are mentioned there, so I perhaps the derivation is correct. Why the aforementioned error terms?

Comment: I _think_ the idea is that you look at f(x) and you can be in error by a maximum of the grid-size in either direction - above or below f(x).  So there's an error-bar (I suppose; I'm not good with stats terminology) of total length $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ around f(x) that is the maximum error you could have.

Comment: I think he's assuming continuity then and that $n$ is large. Is that correct?

Comment: The description of $f$ is absolutely bizarre.  It appears to be a mapping from a scalar to another scalar, but the description says "domain of existence in the unit square."  That makes no sense to me.  Such sloppy language and notation is, in my view, immediate grounds for dismissal as a serious text.

Comment: I don't think so; I think he's saying that at each sampling point you will be at most one grid point away from f(x) (if you're thinking in terms of a 2-d graph then that's vertically, with the grid width being horizontal).  f(x) can be discontinuous since you're only sampling at a fixed number of points.

Comment: To belabor the point, he uses $y = f(x)$, then says the "domain" is $0 \le x, y \le 1.$  What kind of mathematician writes something so obviously contradictory?

Comment: @heropup – I understood it to mean that the graph (x,f(x)) lives in $0\leq x,y,\leq 1$.  I wouldn't write it that way myself, but it doesn't seem too hard to follow.

Comment: @heropup he is sometimes sloppy but don't dismiss the text. This book is *very* highly regarded, it is informally known as "Bayesian Bible".

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here exactly. Along one column $[k/\sqrt{n},(k+1)/\sqrt{n}]$, you are basically saying that $\lfloor \sqrt{n} f(k/\sqrt{n}) \rfloor$ of the squares should be filled and the remainder should not be filled. If the graph of $f$ in that column fits entirely into one square, then the error in this column is no more than the area of one square, which is $1/n$. (I'm not sure I understand where the $2$ is coming from.)

Comment: But if the graph of $f$ in that column does not fit entirely into one square, then the error could be much larger; indeed it could be arbitrarily close to $1/\sqrt{n}$. For instance $f$ could be piecewise linear, increasing and then decreasing over each column, with slopes of magnitude $\sqrt{n}$. Then the error in each column would be $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$.